# populate view with small squares

Tags: ios, swift

Okay this one really made my head hurt but I'm sure someone smarter than me can figure this out easily.  I have some variables which calculate how many small squares can fit in a view.  I want to programmatically populate this view with small squares in a specific order.  I want to animate this and change colors and all this other stuff but the part I am really struggling with is getting these squares in the right order.  I will try to illustrate the order I'm trying to add these views. I hope this comes out okay.

---

### | 1 | 3 | 6 | 11 | 18 |

### | 4 | 2 | 8 | 13 | 20 |

### | 7 | 9 | 5 | 15 | 22 |

### |12|14|16| 10 | 24 |

### |19|21|23| 25 | 17 |

or another cool way would be:

---

### | 1 | 3 | 8 | 15 | 24 |

### | 4 | 2 | 6 | 13 | 22 |

### | 9 | 7 | 5 | 11 | 20 |

### |16|14|12| 10 | 18 |

### |25|23|21| 19 | 17 |

Okay so incase you don't see the pattern, it starts at the top left.  It moves over 1 and down 1, then populates the cells above that and to the left of it, starting at the outer top and left, and moving inward.

This is the code I have so far:

```
let numberOfColumns: CGFloat = 10
    let w = self.view.frame.width
    let h = self.view.frame.height
    let squareSideLength = w / numberOfColumns
    let numberOfRows = h / squareSideLength
    let area = numberOfColumns * numberOfRows
    let areaInt = Int(ceil(area))


    for i in 1...areaInt {
        self.square.frame = CGRect(x: , y: , width: squareSideLength, height: squareSideLength)
        self.view.addSubview(square)
    }
```

I'm not sure how to do the "for" loop or loop(s) to populate it in this crazy order.  I really hope someone can figure this out!

Comment: Sorry - I didn't directly answer your question.  I will post a solution to your order issue shortly.

Comment: I actually want to change the colors with an animation and possibly flip the squares too but was hoping I could figure that part out once I get the loop part working

Comment: Also I didn't downvote your answer, someone else did.  Not a big deal though.  If you can figure this out i'll be sure to upvote and all that, as this is really making my brain hurt lol :)

Comment: Actually the order doesn't have to be like that, I basically just want it to start in the corner and work it's way across the screen diagonally, so I can make it animate and look cool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this!  This is a complete viewController (example) that:

- Creates a maxtrix of numbers
- Animates the color change of the cell in order of number

Hopefully this gets you closer to what you wanted!

```
import UIKit

class viewController: UIViewController {

  let numberOfRows = 10                   //numberOfRows and columns to you can change as needed
  let numberOfColumns = 10
  var currentNumber = 1                   //set the first value in the table, can start anywhere
  typealias Position = (Int, Int)
  var currentPostion = (0,0)              //start at 0,0 in the grid
  var rows = [[Int?]]()                   //rows will hold an array of columns (which is also an array)

  var boxes = [UIView]()
  var boxTracker = 0
  var timer = NSTimer()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    populateMatrix()                     //create the row/column matrix


    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.05, target: self, selector: #selector(self.timerTicked), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

  }

  func timerTicked() {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0) {
      self.boxes[self.boxTracker].backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    }
    boxTracker += 1
    if boxTracker >= boxes.count {
      timer.invalidate()
    }
  }

  func populateMatrix() {
    rows = createEmptyMatrix()
    while currentPostion < (numberOfRows, numberOfColumns) {
      if valueAtPosition(currentPostion) == nil {         //check the current position
        setValueAtPosition(currentPostion, value: currentNumber)  //if it's nil, assign it the next number and increment it
        currentNumber += 1
      }
      let positionNumber = currentPostion.0
      for pos in (0..<positionNumber).reverse() {   //look up from the current postion and fill it in if it's nil
        let upPosition = (pos, currentPostion.1)
        if valueAtPosition(upPosition) == nil {
          setValueAtPosition(upPosition, value: currentNumber)
          currentNumber += 1
        }
        let leftPosition = (currentPostion.1, pos)   //look left from the current position and fill it in if it's nil
        if valueAtPosition(leftPosition) == nil {
          setValueAtPosition(leftPosition, value: currentNumber)
          currentNumber += 1
        }
      }
      currentPostion = (currentPostion.0 + 1, currentPostion.1 + 1)   //move diagonally 1 postion and start over again!
    }
  }

  func createEmptyMatrix() -> [[Int?]] {
    var viewMatrix = [[Int?]]()
    for _ in 0..<numberOfRows {
      let newColumn = [Int?](count:numberOfColumns, repeatedValue: nil)    //create a column array of nil values and add them to rows
      viewMatrix.append(newColumn)
    }
    return viewMatrix
  }

  func valueAtPosition(position: Position) -> Int? {
    return rows[position.0][position.1]
  }

  func setValueAtPosition(position: Position, value: Int) {
    rows[position.0][position.1] = value
    drawBoxForPosition(position)
  }

  func drawBoxForPosition(position: Position) {
    let row = CGFloat(position.0)
    let column = CGFloat(position.1)
    let itemWidth = self.view.bounds.width / CGFloat(numberOfColumns)
    let itemHeight = self.view.bounds.height / CGFloat(numberOfRows)

    let frame = CGRectMake(row * itemWidth, column * itemHeight, itemWidth, itemHeight)
    let boxView = UIView(frame: frame)
    boxView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    boxView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
    boxView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.view.addSubview(boxView)

    let label = UILabel(frame: boxView.bounds)
    label.text = String(valueAtPosition(position)!)
    label.textAlignment = .Center
    boxView.addSubview(label)

    boxes.append(boxView)
  }
}
```

Comment: If you remove the reverse() on the loop, you get the first layout.

Comment: Also, the 'empty' row/column array values are Optional, so you have to unwrap the values if you use them.  if you want to avoid unwrapping the values, you could populate with '0' and look for 0 instead of nil, but then you can't start the numbering at 0 (if you ever wanted to do that)

Comment: Okay i'm working on it now..I'm really excited about this.  I started messing with it like an hour ago and was doing something similar, trying to move up and over from each diagonal square, until I reach the edge, but I just lack the knowledge and ability to do it and gave up again lol.

Comment: I don't see how it produces it though like it doesn't create the views..that's what I was trying to figure out is how to create the views at the right places in the right order

Comment: Ok.  Happy to add that.

Comment: I didn't need the animation but that looked really cool!  I need to cycle through them and change colors in order 1 by 1.  I think I can figure this part out. I also wanted them to be square but now that I think about it, it wouldn't really go diagonally across the screen properly if there were more rows than columns.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113741/discussion-between-djohnson-and-wayne-filkins).